# How to apply styling in divi code module ?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an HTML which I have used in the content section of the **DIVI code module** (as show below): 

**HTML(Present in the content):**

```
<blockquote><span>BPRO helped me realize the importance of cus- tomer organization and tracking, service track- ing and just being on the top of things behind the scene. The more you grow – the more difficult this becomes – but having the right tools to keep your business organized is just as impor- tant as having the right tools to do job itself.</span> <p>Some Person - Some Day 2018</p></blockquote>
```

[image]

**CSS:**

I have a CSS as well which **I want to apply for the HTML code present in the content**. I am wondering where I should be putting my css codes. The CSS codes which I have is:

```
blockquote {
  padding: 20px 60px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 1.625;
  position: relative;
}

blockquote p {
  text-align: center;
}

blockquote span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

blockquote span:before {
  content: "“";
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #79b83a;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 40px;
  line-height: 0;
}

blockquote span:after {
  content: "”";
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #79b83a;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  bottom: -10px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering where I should be putting the above CSS code. **I tried putting the code in the main element in the advanced section of the code module settings but it didn't work**. 

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using the <kbd>[code I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50226915/933810)</kbd> out yesterday.

You can keep the HTML in your Divi module, and put the CSS in the **Appearance** > **Customizer** > **Additional CSS** section

Edit: It looks like Divi has a [custom CSS](https://divibooster.com/adding-css-to-the-divi-theme/) section as well as a [Per Module, Row, and Section CSS option](https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/advanced-design-settings/), though I'd recommend keeping custom CSS in as few locations as possible.

Comment: Yes, I am using your code yesterday. I am not able to find this in divi code module `Appearance > Customizer > Additional CSS section`.

Comment: It's not a Divi module, it's built into Wordpress. Go to your `/wp-admin` and click on the **Appearance** menu item, underneath that is **Customizer**, and inside that on the bottom left is **Additional CSS**, though I did also add in the answer Divi has a custom CSS area as well if you'd like to use that instead.

Comment: There's also this documentation on a per Module, Row, and Section CSS: https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/advanced-design-settings/

Comment: DIVI do has custom CSS as mentioned, I am wondering how to use custom CSS ? I have put HTML in the **content section** and I am not sure how to use **custom CSS**.

Comment: Did you get my question ?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the Appearance > Customizer > Additional CSS yet? I would try that first. However looking back at your screenshot, it looks like you don't have a `<blockquote>` tag at all (which would explain why the CSS targeting blockquotes isn't working)

Comment: Yeah, that's my mistake.

Comment: I am gonna try in that way.

Comment: I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265637/how-to-align-images-in-a-straight-line-in-word-press-divi-theme). I am wondering if you can give me a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your css also in Divi Code Module Content area, just use 'style' tags:

```
<style> 

your css code goes here:

blockquote {
  padding: 20px 60px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 1.625;
  position: relative;
}
... etc



</style>
```